# C# Generate An IEnumerable from Nested Sparse Dictionaries

Tags: c#, ienumerable

So I have a sparse matrix of elements that is represented as

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, StructuredCell>> CellValues = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, StructuredCell>>();
```

inside a class `StructuredTable`. I would like to be able to write a loop as

```
StructuredTable  table = new StructuredTable();

// Fill the table with values

foreach(StructuredCell cell in table.Cells()) {
    // Fill an alternate structure
}
```

Where any x,y combination inside the bound of the max of the number of columns and rows is returned as null. I can't seem to locate an example that uses `yield` this way.

Comment: So you want to write `Cells()` so that it returns all of the embedded `StructuredCell` values from the nested dictionaries?

Comment: Yeah I would like to write `Cells()` that returns an enumerable list of all the cells, populating the empty ones as empty as it goes. The reason I'm thinking of doing it this way is so the entire list is never completely in memory. I'm assuming that an `IEnumerable` & `yield` doesn't need the complete list in memory but can calculate each as it goes.

Comment: "Where any x,y combination inside the bound of the max of the number of columns and rows is returned as null. " What does that mean?  If you're stuck on using `yield` try something else (like filling a list) that _works_ and then find ways to make it _better_.

Comment: How big are the integer keys in your Dictionary?

Comment: I'm not stuck on using yield, just a curiosity. Say that the only `CellValue` in the dictionary is `CellValues[10][10] = Object` then `Cells()` would return an IEnumerable what would return null values for `CellValues[0][0], CellValues[0][1], CellValues[0][2],...CellValues[1][0],CellValues[1][1],...`

Comment: They could range up to 100,000+ in each direction with a payload of a a few KB.

Comment: Do you have a structure to represent the output?, Or does `StructuredCell` include the X and Y values?

Comment: In some cases yes, I can do a transformation of the dictionary into a known structure. In other times I want to be able to just read the entire matrix as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
public IEnumerable<StructuredCell> Cells(){
    for (int i = 0; i < maxColumn; i++)
        {
            Dictionary<int, StructuredCell> row = null;
            CellValues.TryGetValue(i, out row);
            for (int j = 0; j < maxRow; j++)
            {
                if (row == null) yield return null;
                StructuredCell cell = null;
                row.TryGetValue(j, out cell);
                yield return cell;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This won't return missing values as `null` though will it? The idea is that this dictionary can be 10% full and the `IEnumerable` will return 100% of the cells

Comment: So you need a MaxColumn and MaxRow variables. And use a for loop

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that the keys are resonable small you can do a number of optimizations here.

```
public class DataStructure {
    private const int MAX_VALUE = 100000;
    private readonly Dictionary<long, StructuredCell> CellValues;

    private void Add(int keyOne, int keyTwo, StructuredCell cell) {
        long hashKey = keyOne*MAX_VALUE + keyTwo;

        CellValues[hashKey] = cell;
    }

    private void Remove(int keyOne, int keyTwo)
    {
        long hashKey = keyOne * MAX_VALUE + keyTwo;

        CellValues.Remove(hashKey);
    }

    private IEnumerable<StructuredCell> GetCells() {
        return CellValues.Values;
    }
}
```

You can keep a simple Key->Value dictionary, where the

> key = hash(keyOne, keyTwo)

You don't need any fancy lazy constructs (yield) since you already have the values available.

Comment: Good thinking with the key mapping. I may work that in after I do some performance testing on the yield method for comparison.

Comment: You can use `string` instead of `long` for more readability. `$"{keyOne},{keyTwo}"`

Comment: @Kalten no, because it is far faster to use longs as a key instead of strings. You could try it for yourself and do some profiling.

Comment: Yeah, + a bit of memory savings. However, given that we're working with more complex StructuredCell type, that won't be much, but the indexes (longs) will fit the cache way better (in size and alignment) than strings.